# This is possible to create infinity grid with ExtJs 3.4?

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have a application on ExtJs 3.4 and I need to create grid with ~30 000 rows. I see an example in [sencha site](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.1.0-gpl/examples/grid/infinite-scroll.html). But there is use ExtJs 4.1. When I try do this with ExtJs 3.4 I get errors:

```
TypeError: Ext.require is not a function
TypeError: Ext.Loader is not a function
```

Can I do something like this using ExtJs 3.4? Or should I rewrite whole application on ExtJs 4.1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know this is 4.1 feature only. In previous versions there was a product called LiveGrid but it may not have been free.

Comment: Thank you. I find LiveGrid http://www.ext-livegrid.com/download/#license . But it cost 49 € ((